# JavaScript set interval not working?

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain why the following code below doesn't run an automated sequence of images'. I was able to do this before with my code prior to this now that I have edited it slightly the automation doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

    <img id="Light" src="./red.jpg">
    <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLights()">Change Lights</button>

        <script>

            var List = [
                "./red.jpg",
                "./redyellow.jpg",
                "./green.jpg",
                "./yellow.jpg",
                ];

            window.onload = "ChangeLights()"; 

            var index = -1; 

            function ChangeLights() {
            index ++; 

            var image = document.getElementById('Light'); 
            image.src = List[index % List.length]; 

            }
            setInterval(ChangeLights, 1000)

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've set `window.onload` to a string, so that won't have any effect. Also don't use "Array" as a variable name.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works fine. your html tag at the end is incomplete as well </html>

Comment: It isn't automated, the code is working but normally would be automated

Comment: Could someone please help, I'm running out of time and i just want this to be done.

Comment: I normally don't use Overstack but i heard it was good for its friendly feedback and great support, so if someone could excuse my foul mouth and help me?

Comment: @mhodges—Array is not a [*keyword*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-keywords). But yes, it's a poor choice of variable name.

Comment: @RobG Ehh, yes I misspoke. To clarify - `Array` is an identifier for the built-in array constructor function. Reassigning this would cause you to lose the ability to create non array-literal arrays.

Comment: Despite the poor programming issues, the code is syntactically correct and "works" to the extent that the image is changed about every second. You will need to explain "not working", see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is working... You don't need the event on button and you also don't need to assign the function to window.onload, also, you have to remove the double quotations from the function name, AND remove the parenthesis, like this `window.onload = ChangeLights;`, if you call the function, you'll be passing the RETURN of the function to window.onload, which in this case is `undefined`...

EDIT: JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qe0vxrt3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, but you can change Array to a different name and call `ChangeLights();` without "" in line 18 .

Comment: There's no need for *window.onload* at all, the function is initiated by `setInterval(ChangeLights, 1000)`. If *window.onload* was necessary, then the function should be assigned, not the result of calling the function, i.e. `window.onload = changeLights` with no parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The automation works, but the path to the images is wrong, you should fix that by pointing to the right folder, probably by removing the "./" on "./NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE".

Comment: No offence but the images are displaying, if the image path was incorrect why are the images appearing?